# Add column of grouped max - min?

Tags: pandas

I'm new to pandas and going in circles trying different ways to accomplish this.

The data I'm interested in has columns of label and elapsed_duration_ms for example

```
turn_data.loc[:, ['label', 'elapsed_duration_ms']].head()
                    label  elapsed_duration_ms
601  1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB                60100
602  1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB                60200
603  1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB                60300
604  1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB                60400
605  1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB                60500
```

I want to find the difference between the max & min values for "elapsed_duration_ms" which I can get by grouping on label like so

```
grouped = turn_data.groupby('label')
elapsed_time_data = (
    grouped['elapsed_duration_ms'].max() -
    grouped['elapsed_duration_ms'].min())
elapsed_time_data
label
1:21.46 Lap 13  *PoB    13700
1:22.11 Lap 14          13800
1:22.16 Lap 8           13800
1:22.17 Lap 2           13700
Name: elapsed_duration_ms, dtype: int64
```

I'm unsure what to do from here.  My ultimate goal is create bar graphs of the max-min per label.  My assumption is I want to add a new column of the max-min?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 400, 500, 600]})
```

returns:

```
    A   B
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   400
4   b   500
5   b   600
```

then:

```
df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x)).reset_index()
```

returns:

```
    A   B
0   a   2
1   b   200
```